# chemical formulas for drupal like mathjax

Tags: drupal, mathjax

i am trying to put together a Forum for Scientists of Chemistry, and was wondering if there is a plugin for Drupal that allows us to share chemical Formulas via our forum. Right at the moment this is done by ASCII art, but it is a bit tedious, of course.

I was pretty astonished how beautifully mathjax worked for mathematical formulas and now i am looking for a similar solution for chemical formulas. (Using chemstyle perhaps).

I already posted a question at webmasters.stackoverflow, but it did not turn out anything. Perhaps someone here knows of a way to get to my goal? Is it possible to teach Drupal some Latex with chemstyle enabled or is there a cool trick out there to get me what i want to have?

Looking  forward to good answers,
cheers

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate slightly to say this because it seems like such an obvious solution, but there is a [Drupal MathJax module](http://drupal.org/project/mathjax).

It provides an input filter which you could assign to the text format available to your forum users and voila, you have MathJax integrated with the forum.

See [Displaying mathematics with TeX](http://drupal.org/node/159031) for more info.

Comment: I am not looking for something that sets mathematics. Now i am looking for a similar solution for chemical formulas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Drupal module that I'm aware of that will do chemical diagrams but you can feel free to check out either of these solutions to see if you can integrate them into Drupal (of course, you'd have to do the integration yourself):

ChemDoodle: http://web.chemdoodle.com/

MarvinSketch: http://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/marvinsketch/